# Code not generating desired output directory structure in HDFS

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to generate a specific directory structure in HDFS, the code reads data from a kafka topic of different formats and writes the data to HDFS using the following code

```
import logging
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyarrow.hdfs as hdfs
import os

# Configure logging
logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger("org.apache.kafka").setLevel(logging.WARN)

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaToHDFS") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Kafka broker configuration
kafka_server = "sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com:6667"
kafka_topic = "airbnbdata-final"

# Read data from Kafka topic
df = spark.read \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_server) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic) \
    .load()

# Define a function to create the output directory
def create_directory(directory):
    current_time = spark.sql("SELECT current_timestamp()").collect()[0][0]

    # Extract year, month, day, and hour components
    year_str = current_time.strftime("%Y")
    month_str = current_time.strftime("%m")
    day_str = current_time.strftime("%d")
    hour_str = current_time.strftime("%H")
    fulldirectory = directory + "/" + year_str + "/" + month_str + "/" + day_str + "/" + hour_str + "/"
    return fulldirectory

# Define a function to process each batch
def process_batch(df, fulldirectory):
    schema = StructType().add("file_type", StringType()).add("file_name", StringType()).add("data", StringType())

    # Extract the key, value, and other columns
    extracted_df = df.selectExpr(
        "CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "topic", "partition", "offset", "timestamp", "timestampType"
    )

    # Parse the JSON string in the value column
    extracted_df = extracted_df.withColumn("value_json", from_json(col("value"), schema))

    # Extract fields from the value_json column
    extracted_df = extracted_df.withColumn("file_type", col("value_json.file_type"))
    extracted_df = extracted_df.withColumn("file_name", col("value_json.file_name"))
    extracted_df = extracted_df.withColumn("data", col("value_json.data"))

    extracted_df.printSchema()
    return extracted_df

# Define a custom function to write each file to HDFS
def write_file(row, fulldirectory):
    fs = hdfs.connect(host="sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com", port=8020)
    file_name = row["file_name"]
    data = row["data"]

    hdfs_path = fulldirectory + file_name
    with fs.open(hdfs_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)

# Define a function to process images and videos
def process_images_and_videos(df, fulldirectory):
    # Filter the dataframe to get only images and videos
    image_df = df.filter(col("file_type").isin(["jpg", "png"]))
    video_df = df.filter(col("file_type").isin(["mp4", "mov"]))

    # Write images to HDFS
    image_df.foreach(lambda row: write_file(row, fulldirectory + "images/"))

    # Write videos to HDFS
    video_df.foreach(lambda row: write_file(row, fulldirectory + "videos/"))

# Configure the directory path and create the output directory
directory_path = "hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/hadoop/OUTPUT_FINAL1"
fulldirectory = create_directory(directory_path)

# Process the batch
processed_df = process_batch(df, fulldirectory)

# Write each batch to HDFS as Parquet
processed_df.write \
    .format("parquet") \
    .mode("append") \
    .partitionBy("file_type", "file_name") \
    .parquet(fulldirectory + "csv/")

# Process images and videos
process_images_and_videos(processed_df, fulldirectory)

# Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

The output must be saved to HDFS with the following directory:

```
user/hadoop/OUTPUT_FINAL1/
    ├── year/
    │   ├── month/
    │   │   ├── day/
    │   │   │   ├── hour/
    │   │   │   │   ├── csv/
    │   │   │   │   │   └── <csv files> (save as parquet or .csv)
    │   │   │   │   ├── images/
    │   │   │   │   │   └── <image files>
    │   │   │   │   └── videos/
    │   │   │   │       └── <video files>
```

However, when I run this code, it keeps generating all the files under the csv/ directory and it then shows file_type= and file_name= which I Dont need to see in my output directory.

I just need the code to classify videos, csv files and images and store the data in their corresponding directories with the structure I provided above.

I am running on Ambari Sandbox SSH on Python version 2.7.5.